# How to call Function in cx_Oracle with COMPARISON_TYPE returnType and Boolean input?

Tags: python, database, oracle, plsql, cx-oracle

I am trying to call the [COMPARE function](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_comparison.htm#ARPLS870) from the [DBMS_COMPARISON package](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_comparison.htm#ARPLS868)

I first create my comparison by

```
import cx_Oracle

host = host
service_name = service_name
port = port
password = password
username = username


dsn = cx_Oracle.makedsn( host, port,
                         service_name=service_name )
db = cx_Oracle.connect(username, password, dsn )

keyword_parameters = {
        'comparison_name':'my_comparison',
        'schema_name':'my_schema',      
        'object_name':'table_name',
        'dblink_name':'db_link'
}
cur.callproc('DBMS_COMPARISON.CREATE_COMPARISON', keywordParameters = keyword_parameters)
```

Now I want to call the function `DBMS_COMPARISON.COMPARE`

```
DBMS_COMPARISON.COMPARE(
   comparison_name  IN   VARCHAR2,
   scan_info        OUT  COMPARISON_TYPE,
   min_value        IN   VARCHAR2   DEFAULT NULL,
   max_value        IN   VARCHAR2   DEFAULT NULL,
   perform_row_dif  IN   BOOLEAN    DEFAULT FALSE)
RETURN BOOLEAN;
```

I have tried

```
cur.callfunc('DBMS_COMPARISON.COMPARE', int,
             keywordParameters={'comparison_name':'my_comparison', 'scan_info':cur.var(int), 'perform_row_dif':'TRUE'})
```

Or some variant of.  I am having trouble understanding how to set the `returnType` specified in the callfunc and also how to set the required boolean value for the `DBMS_COMPARISON.COMPARE` function call

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example that works for me, anyway! The key is to pass the type of "bool" to the call to cursor.callfunc().

```
create function IsNumber (a_Value varchar2) return boolean is
    t_Value number;
begin
    begin
        t_Value := to_number(a_Value);
        return true;
    exception
    when others then
        return false;
    end;
end;
/
```

And the equivalent Python code is as follows:

```
print(cursor.callfunc("IsNumber", bool, ("5",)))
print(cursor.callfunc("IsNumber", bool, ("Fred",)))
```

This will output the values

True
False